# Why does the date format change after aggregating a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I am trying to group by a few columns, and then aggregate the rest to show a list of unique values.

For example `df =`

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A11 | A21 | A31 | A41 | 01/02/2021 |
| A11 | A22 | A32 | A42 | nan |
| A13 | A23 | A3 | A43 | 01/02/2021 |

After performing

```
df = df.groupby(['A1']).agg(set)
```

the dataframe becomes `df =`

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A11 | A21, A22 | A31, A32 | A41, A42 | {'1612376000000000','nan'} |
| A13 | A23 | A33 | A43 | {'1612376000000000',} |

And it becomes difficult to change the date format back to its original. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What is your pandas version? For me working well.

Comment: My pandas version is 1.1.3 @jezrael

Comment: It is a bit old, `(October 5, 2020)` - [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/index.html), is possible upgrade?

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I've updated it to 1.3.2 and restarted my kernel but I am still unable to get the correct date formats :-(

Comment: I test in `1.2.4` and working well for me

Comment: ah I've found the problem!! it is because I had a step before where I replaced the np.nan with 'nan' and it changed the data type, resulting in the wrong format

Answer (score 1):

For me working well, for lists use:

```
df['A5'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A5'])

df = df.groupby(['A1']).agg(lambda x: list(set(x)))
print (df)
             A2          A3          A4                          A5
A1                                                                 
A11  [A21, A22]  [A31, A32]  [A41, A42]  [NaT, 2021-01-02 00:00:00]
A13       [A23]       [A33]       [A43]       [2021-01-02 00:00:00]
```